# Dividir byte en 8 bits en delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010, delphi-berlin

quiero con un `byte` tratar los días de la semana, es decir que:

```
Lunes -> 1bit
Martes  ->1bit
Miercoles ->1bit
Jueves ->1bit
Viernes ->1bit
Sabado ->1bit
Domingo ->1bit
Todos ->1bit
```

El caso es que no se muy bien como hacerlo. Está claro que un `byte` va de `0` a `255`; lo que quiero es, cuando selecciono un `checkbox`, por ejemplo de lunes y martes que el bit 1 y bit 2 tengan un valor y sumado ese valor lanzarlo a un campo de la base de datos que se llama `Dia` que es un `smallint`...

Es decir, `checkbox` de lunes y martes activos por lo tanto bit1 y bit2 tienen un valor cuando los sumo y lo mando a la base de datos con una query. Mi duda es como separar ese byte en 8 bits para hacer esto.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias partes en este problema y tal vez deberías concretar si tienes problemas en alguna de ellas.

- Por un lado debes convertir el resultado de los `checkbox` en una
  cadena (en formato binario y viceversa); Esta posiblemente sea la más
  simple.
- Por otro lado debes convertir un múmero en base2, por ejemplo
  `"11100000"` en base10 (decimal) para almacenarlo en un entero de la
  Base de Datos; Y también el proceso inverso.

Aquí tienes un par de procedimientos para esto último:

```
// Convierte un número en base10 a base2
function IntToBin(IValue: Int64): String;
var
  RetVar: string;
begin
  RetVar := '';
  IValue := byte(IValue);
  while IValue <> 0 do begin
    RetVar := char(48 + (IValue and 1)) + RetVar;
    IValue := IValue shr 1;
  end;
  if RetVar = '' then
    RetVar := '0';
  Result := RetVar;
end;


// convierte un número en base2 a base10
function BinToInt(BinStr: String): Int64;
var
  i: byte;
  RetVar: Int64;
begin
  BinStr := UpperCase(BinStr);
  if BinStr[length(BinStr)] = 'B' then
    Delete(BinStr, length(BinStr), 1);
  RetVar := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(BinStr) do  begin
    if not(BinStr[i] in ['0', '1']) then begin
      RetVar := 0;
      Break;
    end;
    RetVar := (RetVar shl 1) + (byte(BinStr[i]) and 1);
  end;
  Result := RetVar;
end;
```

El resultado de utilizarlas será algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El número resultante de la conversión ya se puede almacenar en un entero en la Bae de Datos (del tipo que necesitas) sin problemas.

Comment: +1 ¡ Con animación de muestra y todo ! :-O

Answer (score 4):

En pascal, en general, puedes utilizar mascaras de bits individuales y los operadores binarios `and`, `or`, `xor` para *trabajar* con los bits individuales dentro de un Byte.

También se pueden utilizar operadores de *corrimiento* de bits `shl` y `shr`.

Yo usualmente declaro constantes para facilitarme el trabajo, por ejemplo (contando los bits del 1 al 8 de derecha a izquierda)<sup>1</sup>

```
const
  bit1: Byte = $01; {00000001}
  bit2: Byte = $02; {00000010}
  bit3: Byte = $04; {00000100}
  bit4: Byte = $08; {00001000}
  bit5: Byte = $10; {00010000}
  bit6: Byte = $20; {00100000}
  bit7: Byte = $40; {01000000}
  bit8: Byte = $80; {10000000}
```

Con esto, puedes establecer los bits individuales de una variable, utilizando el operador `or`, por ejemplo:

```
var
  MiBit: Byte;

begin
  MiBit := bit1 or bit3 or bit5; {00010101}
  MiBit := MiBit or bit8; {10010101}
```

También puedes comprobar si un bit individual está encendido o apagado, utilizando el operador `and`:

```
  if MiBit and bit6 = bit6 then
    ShowMessage('Bit 6 está encendido');
  if MiBit and bit3 = bit3 then
    ShowMessage('Bit 3 está encendido');
  if MiBit and bit7 = 0 then
    ShowMessage('Bit 7 está apagado');
```

Finalmente, sugeriría, si para ti cada bit es un día de la semana, utilices constantes que ayuden a que el código sea más legible, digamos:

```
const
  bitDomingo: Byte = $01; {00000001}
  bitLunes: Byte = $02; {00000010}
  bitMartes: Byte = $04; {00000100}
  bitMiercoles: Byte = $08; {00001000}
  bitJueves: Byte = $10; {00010000}
  bitViernes: Byte = $20; {00100000}
  bitSabado: Byte = $40; {01000000}

var
  DiasSeleccionados: Byte;

procedure TForm1.CheckBoxDomingoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBoxDomingo.Checked then
    DiasSeleccionados := DiasSeleccionados or bitDomingo
  else
    DiasSeleccionados := DiasSeleccionados and not bitDomingo;
end;
```

---

**<sup>1</sup>** Ojo, que alguien con formación en c, pedirá que los bits vayan del 0 al 7, es una cuestión de convención y puede ser, al final, de cualquier manera, siempre y cuando todos los programadores involucrados en el proyecto estén informados de ella.

Comment: Fantástica explicación Juan Antonio!

Comment: Gracias Germán, creo que se puede ampliar un poco más aún, pero ando corto de tiempo, veremos si le puedo dedicar un rato más en los próximos días.... :)